# Laravel - Filter query with another query

Tags: php, laravel

Pretty simple question.

I have a query:

```
$submissions = Submission::where('removed', 0)
               ->where('deleted', 0)
               ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
               ->paginate(40);
```

I want my other query

```
$savedSubmissionArray = SavedSubmission::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get('id');
```

to filter results based on `$submissions` by matching the id of the submission with the `'submission_id'` field of the SavedSubmission.

My attempt at this was:

```
$submissions = DB::table('submissions')->where('removed', 0)
               ->where('deleted', 0)
               ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
               ->paginate(40);

$savedSubmissionArray = DB::table('SavedSubmission')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                       ->joinSub($submissions, 'submissions', function ($join) {
                             $join->on('saved_submissions.submission_id', '=', 'submissions.id');       
                       })
                       ->get('id');
```

but I'm not entirely sure that joinsub was what I'm supposed to be using here, as it returns:

> InvalidArgumentException No message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
$data = DB::table('submissions') 
            ->join('saved_submissions', 'submissions.id', '=', 'saved_submissions.submission_id')
            ->where(['submissions.removed' =>0, 'saved_submissions.user_id' => Auth::user()->id']) 
            ->select('fields you want to select') 
            ->get();
```

Add more fields according to your needs in where clause to filter the results